# Amazon MWAA, postgresql connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, airflow, psycopg2, mwaa

I try to connect to RDS postgres database with Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA). And I receive a timeout error.
But when I try to connect to this database **not in** Airflow environment, I can do this without any issues.

I allow all Inbound and Outbound traffic in Security Policy for MWAA.

Executed code:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="###.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com", dbname="###", user="###", password="###", port=5432)

print(conn)
```

Received error (on MWAA only).

```
ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 221, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 209, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/test_dag.py", line 32, in test
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="###.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com", dbname="###", user="###",
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ password="###", port=5432)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "###.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (1.23.45.67), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```